# UI for a webpage to get feedback on Twitter

Tags: forms, gui-design, design-patterns, feedback

A webpage I'm designing, is loaded with information about the client's technology capabilities. They want a feature/way where their users give them feedback on the product roadmap in two ways:

1. Form submission - which I've designed as an expand/collapse option. I've called out a cell where we are asking for feedback and there are other cells like this. But hyperlinking each cell to feedback form seems redundant. Please tell me what you think.
2. By way of Twitter - I've no clue how else this can be done other than placing the Twitter icon around the area. And, this looks awkward according to me.
   [image: Snapshot of WIP UI]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing.My question is - How to ask users to tweet their suggestions? Is there any UI pattern that I can use other than placing the Twitter icon there.

Answer (score 2):

"Tweet your suggestions @yourtweetname"